# loadByEmail() is not fetching customer details while using in forgotPasswordPost method in Magento 1.9?

Tags: php, magento-1.9, forgot-password

I have tried 3 different methods but neither one of them is working. My code in the file is -

```
      $customer = $this->_getModel('customer/customer')
                 ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
                 ->loadByEmail($email);
```

It returns nothing.

Please suggest some solution on this.

Comment: What are the output of `var_dump($emai)l` and `var_dump($customer)`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Geoffrey, var_dump($email) output is "xyz@gmail.com" and var_dump($customer) output is empty

Comment: @Community, I want to fetch the customer details from the database, but it returns nothing